# Using min, max within template declarations

Tags: c++, templates

Say I have a polynomial class where the degree is controlled by a template, such as the following:

```
template<int degree>
class Polynomial {
....
}
```

How can I create an Add function that adds two polynomials of potentially different degrees? Ideally it would be something like

```
template<int degree1, int degree2>
Polynomial<max(degree1, degree2)> Add(Polynomial<degree1> poly1, Polynomial<degree2> poly2)
{
...
}
```

Is there a way to do this in c++?

Comment: Why do you want degree to be a template argument. Seems to me it should simply be a member of Polynomial.

Comment: To get compile-time optimization.

Comment: You know that max(a,b) is just (a<b)?b:a, right?

Comment: Calling a function inside of a template parameter. Good luck stepping through that, since that happens at compile time, not run time.

Comment: @CJohnson: How much steps do you expect inside a `max` function anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++11 you can use a `constexpr` function for this:

```
constexpr int max(int n1, int n2)
{ return (n1>n2?n1:n2); }

template <int N1, int N2>
Polynomial<max(N1,N2)> add(const Polynomial<N1> &p1, const Polynomial<N2> &p2)
{ return /*...*/ }
```

Whereas in pre-C++11, there is no concept of `constexpr` functions, but the ternary conditional operator can still be used directly:

```
template <int N1, int N2>
Polynomial<(N1>N2?N1:N2)> add(const Polynomial<N1> &p1, const Polynomial<N2> &p2)
{ return /*...*/ }
```

Comment: The ternary operator is not a must. A meta function can also be used (e.g. boost::mpl::max).

Comment: There is no constexpr in C++03, but you can always define a helper class: template<int a,int b>struct max{static const int value=(a<b)?b:a;};` and use `max<N1,N2>::value`.

Comment: @lego Yes, sure. What I meant was _you can't put the comparison in a function and call that_. I have made the wording clearer now.

Comment: For the sake of illustration, why not make the function a template?

Answer (score 1):

```
template<int degree>
class Polynomial{
...
};

template<int degree1, int degree2>
Polynomial<(degree1<degree2)?degree2:degree1>
Add(Polynomial<degree1> poly1, Polynomial<degree2> poly2)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`std::min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) or [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) from the algorithm header:

```
#include <algorithm>

template<int degree1, int degree2>
Polynomial<std::max(degree1, degree2)> Add(Polynomial<degree1> poly1, Polynomial<degree2> poly2)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This does not work because it is not a constant expression. You have to use constexpr or the ternary operator